# Regex: Validate string as alphabetic capital or capital snake case

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a `regex` to validate a string to accept only alphabetic capital or capital snake case:

Valid:

```
HELLO
HELLO_WORLD
HELLO_WORLD_HELLO_WORLD
```

Invalid:

```
123
___
HELLO WORLD
hello_world
HELLO_WORLD HELLO
```

I created this to accept capital alphabetic snake case:

```
^[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)
```

But I need to allow one-word strings as well.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*$
```

[Online regex for above code](https://regex101.com/r/hWp4aV/1)

***Explanation:***

```
^[A-Z]+    ##Simply checking if value starting from capital letters A to Z with 1 or more occurrences.
(?:        ##Starting a non capturing group here.
_[A-Z]+    ##Mentioning _ and one or more occurrences of A to Z here.
)*         ##Closing non capturing group here with * to look for one or more occurrences.
$          ##Till end of the value.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^[A-Z]+(?:[_][A-Z]+)*$
```

Results [here](http://regexr.com/5nqj5):

```
AAAA - yes
AAAa - no
aaa - no
aaa_ - no
aaa_a - no
aAa_a - no
AAAA_B - yes
```

Comment: You can include numbers
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$